# MySQL procedures check

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web-services

I am new to procedures and I am trying to implement them within my customer website.

I want to create a procedure to add a new customer. I want to check to make sure there phoneNumber is not already in the database. If it is, I want to display an error message. If the phone number is not in the db, I want to insert it into my CUSTOMER table.

I have implemented the following but I am getting an error. I am not sure if I am declaring variables right in MySQL, and I am not sure if the "if statement" is valid in the way I have done it. Also, how could I set the if statement query to a variable? If anyone could help, it would mean a lot. Thanks!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_Customer
(IN customerNum int, 
IN last varchar, 
IN first varchar)
BEGIN
DECLARE output var DEFAULT '';
IF SELECT CUSTOMER.customerNum FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.customerNum= customerNum 
THEN
SET output= "Customer already exists!";
select output;
ELSE
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (customerNum, last, first);
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

**EDITED**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_Customer
(IN customerNum int, 
IN last varchar, 
IN first varchar)
BEGIN
DECLARE output var DEFAULT '';
DECLARE var_num INT;
SELECT CUSTOMER.customerNum INTO var_num FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.customerNum= customerNum 
if var_num IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (customerNum, last, first);
ELSE
SET output= "Customer already exists!";
select output;
END IF;
END//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: What type of data is CUSTOMER.customerNum ?

Comment: @alditis It is an integer... simply the customer number. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE var_num INT;
SELECT CUSTOMER.customerNum INTO var_num FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.customerNum= customerNum
IF var_num IS NULL THEN
    INSERT INTO CUSTOMER VALUES (customerNum, last, first);
ELSE
    SET output= "Customer already exists!";
    select output;
ENDIF;
...
```

Comment: Thank you but i believe the IF only checks if it is null... do you know how it could check if the customerNum itself is not in the database? Thanks again

Comment: The SELECT finds the customerNum in the database and assign it to var_num if found. If not found, var_num be NULL. Try.

Comment: It is saying there is an error near BEGIN DECLAR outpu' at line 3. Any Idea why? Thanks, will accept as soon as code works

Comment: Change to: DECLARE output VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';

Comment: Still not working. I think the quotes might be the problem? I did this DECLARE output VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';

Comment: Change: DECLARE output var DEFAULT '';

Comment: To: DECLARE output VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT '';

Comment: Still the same error... It has something to do with how we are declaring our variables I believe. Are they in the wrong location?

Comment: Or does varchar in the parameters need a number?

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE add_Customer
(IN customerNum int, 
IN last VARCHAR(50), 
IN first VARCHAR(50))